# Wi-Fi adapter making Ubuntu unresponsive

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

thanks in advance for helping me out

I am an ubuntu newbie here.

I have narrowed my issue down to something related to my current Wi-Fi usb adapter
 https://www.netgear.com/support/product/A6210.aspx

These are the symptoms I am seeing:

- 5.4.0-42-generic
  Known working version
- 5.4.0-56-generic
  Unplugged, system is responsive
  As soon as the wifi adapter is plugged in, the system becomes unresponsive

Any pointers in how I can narrow down this issue further?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```